# Infinite Dimensional Optimization in Support Vector Machines

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

In the kernelized form of the SVM, we are trying to solve the problem

\begin{align}
\min_{w \in H, \, b \in R} \quad &\frac{1}{2} ||w||^2 + C \sum_{i = 1}^N \xi_i \\
\text{s.t.} \quad &y_i f(x_i) \geq 1 - \xi_i, \quad \forall i \\
&\xi_i \geq 0 \quad \forall i
\end{align}

where $f (x) := \left<w, h(x)\right> + b$, and $h$ is a mapping that expands the original feature space $X$ into the enlarged space $H$. The space $H$ is equipped with the inner product $\left< \cdot, \cdot \right>$ and by extension the norm $||\cdot||$.

However, when deriving the dual form of this problem, all the sources I've run into seem to treat $h (x)$ as finite dimensional and $\left<w, h(x)\right>$ as a standard dot-product, whereas the most popular kernel, the RBF kernel, actually projects data points $x$ into an infinite-dimensional space, where the inner product is the $L^2$-norm. In particular, these sources when solving for the dual simply "differentiate" the Lagrangian "with respect to" $w$, even though this is not formally correct.

What is really going on here? I have not taken a course on functional analysis or calculus of variations so the process of optimizing a function of infinitely many variables is foreign to me. Any clarifications or directions to appropriate source materials would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_derivative and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative

Comment: I've posted a very similar question on stats.se and still have got no answers; did you manage to understand how the optimization problem is solved when $H$ is not $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/551585/340026

Comment: Refer to Support Vector Machines by Christmann and Steinwart (you can easily obtain a free pdf via googling). This boils down essentially to the representer theorem (page 168), which states that the empirical SVM solution is a linear combination of feature maps evaluated at the (finite) data - thus finite dimensional. For a full derivation of the dual problem look from page 412.